# Azure push notification not displayed

Tags: ios, iphone, azure, apple-push-notifications, azure-hub

This is the template I am setting on registering for azure hub :

```
NSString* template = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"aps\":{\"alert\":\"$(message)\",\"badge\":\"#(badge)\",\"url\":\"$(message)\",\"inAppMessage\":\"$(message)\" }}"];

        [hub registerTemplateWithDeviceToken:deviceToken name:@"notificationTemplate" jsonBodyTemplate:template expiryTemplate:@"0" tags:[NSSet setWithObjects:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_%@", HUBNAME, token], nil]  completion:^(NSError* error) {
            if (error != nil) {
                NSLog(@"Error registering for notifications: %@", error);
            }
            else {
                NSLog(@"Registered !!");
            }
        }];
```

When sender sends the notification, I just receive the badge but no notification is received.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `title` key in the template. Check with this template and send the notification according to that:

```
"{\"aps\":{\"alert\":\"$(message)\",\"title\":\"$(title)\",\"badge\":\"#(badge)\",\"url\":\"$(message)\",\"inAppMessage\":\"$(message)\" }}"
```